# Intuition degeneracy maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, intuition, simplicial-stuff

I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding for the notion of a [simplicial set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set). Roughly, a *simplicial set* consists of a set $S_n$ of *$n$-simplices* for each non-negative $n$, and families of *face maps* $\{d_i\colon S_n\to S_{n-1}\}_{0\leq i\leq n}$ and *degeneracy maps* $\{s_i\colon S_n\to S_{n+1}\}_{0\leq i\leq n}$.

I'm interpreting this intuitively as follows: the sets $S_n$ tell us *what to glue*. Elements of $S_0$ are interpreted as points, elements of $S_1$ as lines, elements of $S_2$ as triangles, elements of $S_3$ as tetrahedrons, and so on. The face maps tell us *how to glue*. For instance, if we want to glue two triangles $\Delta_1, \Delta_2\in S_2$ both on the "first" line, we let $d_0 \Delta_1 = d_0\Delta_2$.

But here is a specific question I'm wondering about: what's the role of the degeneracy maps? Why do I need to know them in the process of glueing all the elements of the $S_n$ together? It seems the face maps suffice, because they tell us which simplices have which vertices.

Answer (score 7):

Degeneracy maps are indeed totally unnecessary to describe the simplicial set you're interested in, and in fact it's possible to do simplicial homotopy theory with *semisimplicial sets*, which are precisely simplicial sets without the degeneracy maps. However, the connection with topological spaces is weaker. For instance, the singular simplicial set of the one-point topological space has geometric realization homeomorphic to that space. But the geometric realization of the singular semi-simplicial set of *any* nonempty topological space is infinite-dimensional, as a CW complex! There's no way to collapse away the simplices that really aren't carrying any information. If you want to work with nice finite semisimplicial sets, like say the one with one $0$-simplex and no higher-dimensional simplices, then you realize that, unfortunately, most semi-simplicial sets cannot map into it! So you have to do some "fattening up" to get such a semisimplicial set to actually behave like a topological point. All of these issues are entirely fixable, but the communicty has preferred the degenerate solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. But could you describe intuitively *how* the information of the degeneracy maps is used exactly in the glueing process?

Comment: Certainly, it's simple enough: the geometric realization is the Yoneda extension of the standard embedding of the simplex category into Top. That means that, if you write a simplicial set as the colimit of all its simplices and all ways these simplices factor through each other, its geometric realization is the same colimit of spaces. Any degenerate simplex in a simplicial set $X$ factors through a lower-dimensional simplex, so the same factorization happens on the geometric realization $|X|.$ In particular, degenerate $1$-simplices get squished to constant paths in the geometric realization.

Comment: @user978360 Here's a nice introduction with some pictures, if you like. https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4221

Comment: I know that document, but I don't have the time to read a 60 page document. I only want to know one specific question: Intuitively, how is the information of the degeneracy maps used in the glueing process? I just want to get a concise answer to that. The formal Yoneda construction doesn't count as "geometrically intuitive" for me. I feel like I haven't got an answer to that. Unfortunately I don't understand what you are saying starting at "Any degenerate simplex". What is a degenerate simplex, when does a simplex factor through another simplex, what is a factorization, what is squishing?

Comment: @user978360 This is a topic usually only studied at the graduate level. It’s going to be unmanageable if you don’t have a lot of time to put in. The fact that you don’t know what “factors through” means suggests you also have too little category theory background for the subject, so if you ever find some time to work, I would start there.

Answer (score -1):

My current understanding is that degeneracy maps are to guarantee the existence, and to provide a "degenerate version" of any given simplex (and a given face the degeneracy happens in). Why should we need this? Because sometimes we want to be able to "collapse" boundaries.

Let's have a triangle $T$. By collapsing its boundary to a point, you can effectively represent the two-dimensional sphere $S_2$ with just a single triangle. But how do you represent this collapse? You can try to identify the edges with each other, but that doesn't guarantee that the edges get reduced to points. Even if you identify their end points, the edge might still be non-zero and form a loop. (Maybe forming a dunce hat?)

But we can get a nice $S_2$ sphere by having a single vertex $v_0$, then taking the degeneracy map on that: $e_0 = s_0(v_0)$. Now we have an edge $e_0$ that isn't an actual edge, but a point in a trench coat. We can then set the triangle's faces to equal the edge: $d_0(T) = e_0$, $d_1(T) = e_0$, $d_2(T) = e_0$. And ta-dah! The edges are now collapsed into a point. We have a $S_2$!

The same idea is presented in [Friedman's book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4221.pdf) (page 27):

[image]